# I can´t drag object into code properties, to connect it to public components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example:

public RigidBody rb;
And then if i go and open Unity i cant drag anything to rb in the components because there isn`t an rb slot.

Comment: Hey there, can you provide us your code? Are you sure it is a monobehaviour and attached to the gameobject?

Comment: Code and/or a screenshot would be good. Sounds like you are trying to describe that rigidbody isn't a child of the object you want it to be attached to.